# Laravel 5.2 Debugging not working and public variable can't able to access

Tags: laravel, debugging, publish

I have a controller like as below

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public $customerColums;

    function _construct()
    {

         $this->customerColums = array('username','unique_id','first_name','email','profile_image','contract_id','address','telephone','priority_id','segment_id','class_id','is_active','is_deleted');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo '<pre>';print_r($this->customerColums);die;
    }
}
```

But this public variable not showing page dispaly as empty and log files are written.

I have given file permission and set debug => TRUE

Nothing showing ? How do I debug?

Comment: check your server logs, Is any other API working ?

Comment: have you ever used mvc pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have there mistake constructor is with two leading underlines not just one `__construct()`. For debuging try to use this `die(var_dump($this->customerColumns));`. It will dump varibale and die.

Comment: It should be `__construct`, not `__constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `public function index()`, not just `public index()`.